# Facebook auto share module with drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am looking for a drupal module where I can do the following

1) Auto share on my fan page content with a certain taxonomy term every day in specific times. For example start on 15:00 and post every 15min until 17:00.

2) Auto share all the new content every day in specific times. If there isn't any new content, then it will stop. If reach the max time and it has more content, then leave it for the next day.

Do you know any module where I can do the above without coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module will do most if not all of what you're looking for, but its a complicated module and I wouldn't know without further information if any bespoke code would be required to meet your specification.

Comment: I have seen that I can combine facebook auto post with rules. I will take a look and if I can do what I need I will vote your answer :)